# Recurrence relation $ T(n)=5^n+3T(\lfloor n^\frac{2}{5}\rfloor) $

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to prove that the following recurrence relation is $O(5^n)$:
$$ T(n)=5^n+3T(\lfloor n^\frac{2}{5}\rfloor) $$
And $T(n)=\Theta(1)$ for $n\le 9$.

I am trying induction, and proving that there exists $c$ such that $T(n)\le c\cdot5^n$, but I am stuck at the induction step:

$T(n)=5^n+3T(\big\lfloor n^\frac{2}{5}\big\rfloor)\le5^n+3c\cdot 5^{\lfloor n^\frac{2}{5}\rfloor}\le5^n+3c \cdot 5^{n^{\frac{2}{5}}}=\bigg(1+\frac{3c}{5^{n- n^\frac{2}{5}}}\bigg)\cdot 5^n$.

How can I continue in the induction (turn the parenthesis into the constant $c$ / is there a different way to prove it?

Comment: Do you know the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))?

Comment: @cgss No, I don't

Comment: I would suggest you give it a look. It's a very useful tool for recurrence relations.  Check case from the link. It's almost what you need.

Comment: @cgss Is there a way to prove it without using the Master Theorem? Because we didn't learn it. For example, how can I complete the induction step?

Comment: For $n\geq 3$, $$
1 + \frac{{3 \cdot 2}}{{5^{n - n^{2/5} } }} < 2,
$$ so you can take $c=2$.

Comment: @cgss The master theorem won't work here, he has $T( n^{0.4} )$ which is most certainly not in the form of $aT( \frac{n}{b} )$ ...

Comment: There's a been a while since I checked the problem but if i recall correctly you could work with inequalities and substitute $n^{0.4}$ with $n$ or something similar to make it work. I can always be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the recurrence

$$
T(n) = 5^n+3T\left(n^a\right)
$$

$$
T\left(a^{\log_a n}\right) = 5^n+3T\left(a^{\log_a n^a}\right)
$$

now making $z = \log_a n,\ \ \mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(a^{(\cdot)}\right)$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) = 5^{a^z}+3\mathcal{T}(a z) 
$$

or

$$
\mathcal{T}(a^{\log_a z}) = 5^{a^z}+3\mathcal{T}(a^{\log_a (a z)}) 
$$

making now $u = \log_a z,\ \ \mathbb{T}(\cdot) = \mathcal{T}\left(a^{(\cdot)}\right)$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{T}(u) = 5^{a^{a^u}}+3\mathbb{T}(u+1)
$$

This recurrence has the solution

$$
\mathbb{T}(u) =3^{1-u}\left(c_1 - \sum_{k=0}^{u-1}3^{k-1} 5^{a^{a^k}}\right)
$$

and going backwards

$$
T(n) = 3^{1-\frac{\ln \left(\frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (a)}\right)}{\ln (a)}}\left(c_1-\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{\ln \left(\frac{\ln (n)}{\ln(a)}\right)}{\ln (a)}-1}3^{k-1} 5^{a^{a^k}}\right)
$$

NOTE

With $a = \frac 25$ and $k = \frac{\ln \left(\frac{\ln (n)}{\ln(a)}\right)}{\ln (a)}-1$

$$
 5^{a^{a^k}} = 5^{n^{\frac 52}}
$$